# Why items are being pushed multiple times to the array unexpectedly instead of once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a couple of checkboxes that are attached to an event and when clicked two values are being pushed to the ingredients and ingredientsPrice array respectively.
When I run it the first time the program seems to work fine however as I start a new order although the values are being reset somehow each item is being repetitively added. I have noticed a pattern of the repetitive process that after each order every  item is added for another one time like there is a loop. Small example below:

```js
var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
var addSandwich = document.getElementById("add-sandwich");
var ingredients = [];
var ingredientsPrice = [];

function getIngredientsInfo() {
  //loop through check boxes

  for (let i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    //add event listener to check boxes
    checkBoxes[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
      if (event.target.checked) {
        //push the name of ingredient to ingredients array
        ingredients.push(event.target.name);
        //push the ingredient price to ingredientsPrice array
        ingredientsPrice.push(event.target.value);
        console.log(ingredients, ingredientsPrice + " current array values");
      } 
    });
  }
}

function resetValues() {

  for (let x = 0; x < checkBoxes.length; x++) {
    checkBoxes[x].checked = false;
  }
  ingredients = [];
  ingredientsPrice = [];
}

getIngredientsInfo();

addSandwich.addEventListener("click", () => {
getIngredientsInfo();
resetValues();
});
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-container">
  <p>Ingredients</p>
    <fieldset class="hidden">
        <legend>Choose your favourite ingredients</legend>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="bacon" name="bacon"
                   value="1.00" />
            <label class="label" for="bacon">Bacon</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="beef" name="Beef"
                   value="1.50"/>
            <label class="label" for="beef">Beef</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="carrot" name="carrot"
                   value="0.50"/>
            <label class="label" for="carrot">Carrot</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="cucamber" name="cucamber"
                   value=".25"/>
            <label class="label" for="cucamber">Cucamber</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="duck" name="Duck"
                   value="1.75"/>
            <label class="label" for="duck">Duck</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chicken" name="Grilled Chicken"
                   value="2.00"/>
            <label class="label" for="chicken">Grilled Chicken</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="ham" name="Ham"
                   value=".5"/>
            <label class="label" for="ham">Ham</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="lettuce" name="Lettuce"
                   value="0"/>
            <label class="label" for="lettuce">Lettuce</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="mushroom" name="Mushrooms"
                   value=".5"/>
            <label class="label" for="mushroom">Mushrooms</label>
        </div>

    

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="hard-boiled-egg" name="Hard Boiled Egg"
                   value=".5" />
            <label class="label" for="hard-boiled-egg">Hard Boiled Egg</label>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
    <div class="order-nav">
          <button type="submit" id="add-sandwich" class="btn pd-x-10" value="submit">Add Sandwich</button>
        </div> 
</div>
```

var arr = [];
arr.push(aa, bb);  <---arr have value of aa and bb now however if I start a new order each item will be added twice.If I start another one after that each item is added three times and it keeps increasing every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding an event listener for every click on `addSandwich` which results in the function being called multiple times. What you need to do is don;t call `getIngredientsInfo()` in the click listener for`addSandwitch`. Change `addSandwich.addEventListener("click", () => {
getIngredientsInfo();
resetValues();
});`
 to
`addSandwich.addEventListener("click", () => {
resetValues();
});`

Answer (score 1):

By `addSandwich`, you create a new event listener for every checkbox.

Just delete `getIngredientsInfo();`

```
addSandwich.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // getIngredientsInfo();
    resetValues();
});
```

```js
var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
var addSandwich = document.getElementById("add-sandwich");
var ingredients = [];
var ingredientsPrice = [];

function getIngredientsInfo() {
  //loop through check boxes

  for (let i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    //add event listener to check boxes
    checkBoxes[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
console.log(event.target.checked)
      if (event.target.checked) {
        //push the name of ingredient to ingredients array
        ingredients.push(event.target.name);
        //push the ingredient price to ingredientsPrice array
        ingredientsPrice.push(event.target.value);
        console.log(ingredients, ingredientsPrice + " current array values");
      } 
    });
  }
}

function resetValues() {

  for (let x = 0; x < checkBoxes.length; x++) {
    checkBoxes[x].checked = false;
  }
  ingredients = [];
  ingredientsPrice = [];
}

getIngredientsInfo();

addSandwich.addEventListener("click", () => {
//    getIngredientsInfo();
resetValues();
});
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-container">
  <p>Ingredients</p>
    <fieldset class="hidden">
        <legend>Choose your favourite ingredients</legend>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="bacon" name="bacon"
                   value="1.00" />
            <label class="label" for="bacon">Bacon</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="beef" name="Beef"
                   value="1.50"/>
            <label class="label" for="beef">Beef</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="carrot" name="carrot"
                   value="0.50"/>
            <label class="label" for="carrot">Carrot</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="cucamber" name="cucamber"
                   value=".25"/>
            <label class="label" for="cucamber">Cucamber</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="duck" name="Duck"
                   value="1.75"/>
            <label class="label" for="duck">Duck</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chicken" name="Grilled Chicken"
                   value="2.00"/>
            <label class="label" for="chicken">Grilled Chicken</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="ham" name="Ham"
                   value=".5"/>
            <label class="label" for="ham">Ham</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="lettuce" name="Lettuce"
                   value="0"/>
            <label class="label" for="lettuce">Lettuce</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="mushroom" name="Mushrooms"
                   value=".5"/>
            <label class="label" for="mushroom">Mushrooms</label>
        </div>

    

        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="hard-boiled-egg" name="Hard Boiled Egg"
                   value=".5" />
            <label class="label" for="hard-boiled-egg">Hard Boiled Egg</label>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
    <div class="order-nav">
          <button type="submit" id="add-sandwich" class="btn pd-x-10" value="submit">Add Sandwich</button>
        </div> 
</div>
```